# Access-token not being stored as cookie after deploying MERN stack website on render.com

Tags: authentication, cookies, access-token, http-status-code-401, render.com

I recently deployed my MERN stack website on render.com, but I'm facing an issue where the access-token is not being stored as a cookie when a user logs in. This functionality works perfectly fine on localhost, but not on the deployed version. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

As the access-token is not being stored as a cookie, **causing a 401 error when making a PUT request. The error message indicates that the request has failed with a status code of 401, which is an unauthorized access error.** I have tried various solutions found online, but none have worked so far. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?"

Error:

xhr.js:247          PUT https://youtube-api-6ocf.onrender.com/api/users/dislike/6432be51574971eda59cd025 401

(anonymous) @ xhr.js:247

xhr @ xhr.js:49

Nd @ dispatchRequest.js:51

value @ Axios.js:142

(anonymous) @ Axios.js:181

(anonymous) @ bind.js:5

(anonymous) @ Video.jsx:147

l @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44

(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125

(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69

Rr @ asyncToGenerator.js:3

a @ asyncToGenerator.js:22

(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27

(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19

(anonymous) @ Video.jsx:146

Le @ react-dom.production.min.js:54

Be @ react-dom.production.min.js:54

(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:55

Mr @ react-dom.production.min.js:105

Ur @ react-dom.production.min.js:106

(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117

lc @ react-dom.production.min.js:274

Re @ react-dom.production.min.js:52

Wr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109

Kt @ react-dom.production.min.js:74

Zt @ react-dom.production.min.js:73

asyncToGenerator.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) Vf {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Answer (score 0):

1-you need to have custom domains cause onredender is a public suffix list and you are not able to store your cookies

2-In your react code withCredential option in Axios  must be ***true***

3-in your back-end : app.use(cors( credentials true )) check your cors as well
I hope it helps you